# Can't write my Excel data to the database, returning a timeout error

Tags: c#, sql-server, excel, asp.net-core-mvc

I can't write my Excel data into the database, it's returning a timeout error:

> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Execution Timeout Expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.
> Operation canceled by user.
> The statement has been terminated.'

I believe it is something that is open and it is taking time to do everything, since in one of the 99 attempts, I managed to insert it into the table.

My code:

```
    public IActionResult EnviarDados([FromForm] IFormFile ArquivoExcel)
    {
        Stream stream = ArquivoExcel.OpenReadStream();

        IWorkbook MiExcel = null;

        if (Path.GetExtension(ArquivoExcel.FileName) == ".xlsx")
        {
            MiExcel = new XSSFWorkbook(stream);
        }
        else
        {
            MiExcel = new HSSFWorkbook(stream);
        }

        ISheet HojaExcel = MiExcel.GetSheetAt(0);

        int cantidadFilas = HojaExcel.LastRowNum;

        List<Produto> lista = new List<Produto>();

        for (int i = 1; i <= cantidadFilas; i++)
        {
            IRow fila = HojaExcel.GetRow(i);

            lista.Add(new Produto
            {
                Name = fila.GetCell(0).ToString(),
                Sku = fila.GetCell(1).ToString(),
                Active = fila.GetCell(2).ToString(),
                Description = fila.GetCell(3).ToString(),
                Price = fila.GetCell(4).ToString(),
                Qty = fila.GetCell(5).ToString(),
                Ean = fila.GetCell(6).ToString(),
                SkuManufacturer = fila.GetCell(7).ToString(),
                NetWeight = fila.GetCell(8).ToString(),
                GrossWeight = fila.GetCell(9).ToString(),
                Width = fila.GetCell(10).ToString(),
                Height = fila.GetCell(11).ToString(),
                Depth = fila.GetCell(12).ToString(),
                Guarantee = fila.GetCell(13).ToString(),
                Origin = fila.GetCell(14).ToString(),
                Unity = fila.GetCell(15).ToString(),
                Ncm = fila.GetCell(16).ToString(),
                Manufacturer = fila.GetCell(17).ToString(),
                ExtraOperatingTime = fila.GetCell(18).ToString(),
                Category = fila.GetCell(19).ToString(),
                Images = fila.GetCell(20).ToString(),
            });
        }

        _dbocontext.BulkInsert(lista);

        return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status200OK, new { mensaje = "Os dados foram carregados com sucesso!" });
    }
```

Comment: How many rows do you have in your excel spreadsheet? I see that you're using `BulkInsert` extension of EF so it should be really fast but anyway.

Comment: At the moment as I'm testing it, it has only 7 rows and 21 columns.

Comment: Have you tried to wrap your stream in using construct, so before inserting you have it disposed?

Comment: I don't understand, but how can I do this?

Comment: For testing purposes, try to insert data in a different table using the BulkInsert. See whether it works or generates similar issues. Is your database located on the same machine or it is on a different server? Try to check that there are no network issues and check the firewall settings. If possible, try to increase the timeout and see whether it makes any difference.

Comment: This same table has already been inserted, but it was one attempt in 99 attempts. The process was supposed to be fast, it's only 7 lines.

Comment: You could check the things I suggested in my previous comment one by one. It may help you narrow down the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try to dispose stream before inserting to the database.
Wrapping stream  in `using` will call `Dispose` method when you're done adding products to the list. Then before doing insert you have other resources freed up.

```
public IActionResult EnviarDados([FromForm] IFormFile ArquivoExcel)
{
    var lista = new List<Produto>();

    using (var stream = ArquivoExcel.OpenReadStream())
    {
        IWorkbook MiExcel = null;
        ...
        for (int i = 1; i <= cantidadFilas; i++)
        {
            IRow fila = HojaExcel.GetRow(i);
            lista.Add(...)
        }
    }

    _dbocontext.BulkInsert(lista);

    return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status200OK,...);
}
```

Comment: I used "using" and put everything inside, but still the same error.

Comment: Hm, that's become interesting :) Have you tried to move your code in a simple console application? Read excel file from disk rather than pass it to API and try to insert data.

Comment: I did not do this. But I managed to run my application when it had fewer columns and when I changed it I managed to run it only once, the rest of the times it gives the "timeout".